# Problem with async operations when querying each map element NodeJS/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose for db connection and is my case, I receive contacts as an array of objects and then go through each of the array elements to try and find a duplicate if it already exists in database, but before this happens, next() is called.

Here's my code

```
  req.body.contacts.map((contact) => {
    Contact.find(
      {
        contact_name: contact.contact_name,
        phone: contact.phone,
        user_id: req.userId,
      },
      (err, contacts) => {
        if (contacts.length > 0) {
          res.status(500).send({ message: "You have already submitted this contact" });
          return;
        } else if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );
  });
  next();
```

Comment: call `next` in the callback - i.e. inside `(err, contacts) => { .... here ... }`

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` then `.map()` is the wrong tool... That should be a `.forEach()`

Comment: You should also use `Contact.findOne`, faster than `.find` because it stops at the first occurrence. You are only looking for one match, not an array of matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spare yourself a few headaches and use the `await` syntax. In case of multiple asynchronous operations, callbacks or `.then()` syntaxes are a nightmare to deal with.

```
for( let contact of contacts) {

    let found,
        conditions = {
            contact_name: contact.contact_name,
            phone: contact.phone,
            user_id: req.userId,
        };
    
    try {
        found = await Contact.findOne(conditions).lean().exec();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    if(found){
        res.status(500).send({ message: "You have already submitted this contact" });
        return;
    }
}

next();
```

Add `.lean()` to get pure JSON (not Mongoose objects, way faster), and `.exec()` to return a true Promise (not a thenable) so you can `await` it cleanly.